# NTLM TLS 1.2 authentication Node.js

Tags: node.js, tls1.2, ntlm, ntlm-authentication

I need to make a get request call to an Api with NTLM TLS 1.2 authentication.
My end-point works with C# and with insomnia app.
But I want to implemented with node.js and postman

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have used all the available libraries.
Axios, https-request.. etc.. but nothing works 
I get ERROR 401 unauthorized        ...every time

my code -->

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.post('url', {
    params: {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        domain: ''
    },
    headers: {
        CultureName: "GR",
        ServicesVersion: "1"

    }
})
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that your credential are correct ? "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials"

Comment: yeah ...
because with insomnia rest Client works

Comment: Looking the same, is there a resolution you found?